# FCM Web Push Notifications not firing

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

I know this question has been asked many times, but I still can't get it working.

I have a firebase cloud function sending notifications through firebase messaging's `sendMulticast` function. This reports success for all tokens. Notifications for iOS and Android are being received.

```js
let res = await admin.messaging().sendMulticast({
  tokens: [...],
  notification: {
    title: title,
    body: body,
  },
  data: {
    ...
  },
  webpush: {
    headers: {
      image: `...`,
    },
    fcmOptions: {
      link: `...`,
    },
  },
  apns: {
    ...
  },
  android: {
    ...
  },
});
```

I'm using SvelteKit's service worker. The service worker is registering and active and if I inspect it through Chrome's devtools I see the "Listening for background messages." log in the console.

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging, onBackgroundMessage } from "firebase/messaging/sw";

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
  ...
});

self.console.log("Listening for background messages.");

onBackgroundMessage(getMessaging(firebaseApp), payload => {
  self.console.log('Background message received', payload);
});
```

On the client, when a user logs in, I'm using firebase messaging to get the token, point it at the sveltekit service worker rather than `firebase-messaging-sw`, and listen for foreground messages. I get the "Listening for foreground messages." log in the browser console.

```js
import { getApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging, onMessage, getToken } from "firebase/messaging";

async function init() {
  let serviceWorkerRegistration = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
  let token = await getToken(getMessaging(getApp()), {
    vapidKey: "...",
    serviceWorkerRegistration: serviceWorkerRegistration,
  });
  console.log('Listening for foreground messages.', token);
  onMessage(getMessaging(getApp()), payload => {
    console.log('Foreground message received. ', payload);
  });
}
```

Trouble is when I send a notification... nothing happens. I don't see the background notification log when the browser is closed or in the background, I don't see the foreground message received log when the browser is focused, I don't get an operating system notification, I don't get any errors... just  nothing.

I've checked the obvious: I'm running mac os, no not disturb is off, notifications are on and allowed for chrome, notifications are allowed for my domain, etc.